# Office sweepstake odds

Tags: probability

There are $32$ teams in the World Cup. There are $4$ favourites. I think the odds, if you are first to draw, of getting a favourite is $4/32$. If the $1$st draw keeps it a secret then the $2$nd to draw is $3/32$. The problem with this if you carry on to the last $4$ teams in the bag is, using my method, the last $4$ will get a favourite team $100\%$.
So each person can only have one ticket, and the ticket is kept secret what are the probabilities for all $32$ people?

Answer (score 0):

The probability for the second to get a favourite given that the first did is actually $3/31$

If you go through the ticket distribution by taking 32 bits of paper out of a bag or something, you know by the symmetry of the situation that every person has a $4/32 = 1/8$ chance of a favourite.